# How to substring from StreamReader ( ReadLine ) when its longer than 256 . c#

Tags: c#, substring, streamreader

I use this function in C#:

```
source = new StreamReader(sFel, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII, false, 512);
```

to make possibility to load longer text,

But I have problem with `Substring`-function when line is longer than 256 chars (it's bigger than string). How can I resolve the problem?

Line which I read is longer than max value of string.

Comment: What language is this? Please [edit] the question and add the applicable tag.

Comment: That's not a function. That's a line. There's no inherent limit in .NET for strings at 256 characters, so you'll need to give us more information about what you're doing - what's the overall goal here, and how does it relate to the line you're showing us?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it. It was stupid mistake:

```
int u = sLinia.IndexOf(",", t + 1);
string s14 = sLinia.Substring(t + 1, u - t - 1); // there should be "t+1" not "u+1"
```

My bad, I thought about range of string.

Answer (score 0):

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length

Code:

```
        srPlik = new StreamReader(sFel, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII, false, 512); //dluzszy ciag znakow niz string czyli 256
        do
        {
            sLinia = srPlik.ReadLine();
            i=sLinia.IndexOf(",",13);
            string kwota  = sLinia.Substring( 13,i-13);

            dKwota_3 = Convert.ToDecimal(kwota)/100; 
            this.tb3.Text = dKwota_3.ToString();

            int j = sLinia.IndexOf(",", i+1);
            string  nr_rozl_odd_nad  = sLinia.Substring( i+1,j-i-1);


                 int k=sLinia.IndexOf(",", j+1);
                 string nr_rozl_odd_odb = sLinia.Substring(j + 1, k - j - 1);


                 int l = sLinia.IndexOf(",", k + 1);
                 string rach_klienta_nadawcy = sLinia.Substring(k + 1, l - k - 1);

                 int m = sLinia.IndexOf(",", l + 1);
                 string rach_klienta_adresata = sLinia.Substring(l + 1, m - l - 1);


                 int n = sLinia.IndexOf(",", m + 1);
                 string nazwaiadres = sLinia.Substring(m + 1, n - m - 1);


                 int o = sLinia.IndexOf(",", n + 1);
                 string s9 = sLinia.Substring(n + 1, o - n - 1);

                 int p = sLinia.IndexOf(",", o + 1);
                 string s10 = sLinia.Substring(o + 1, p - o - 1);

                 int r = sLinia.IndexOf(",", p + 1);
                 string s11 = sLinia.Substring(p + 1, r - p - 1);


                int koniec_tytulu = sLinia.IndexOf('"',r+2); //szukaj cudzysłowia czyli końca tytułu
                string s12 = sLinia.Substring(r + 1, koniec_tytulu - r -2-1);


                 int t = sLinia.IndexOf(",", koniec_tytulu + 2);
                string s13 = sLinia.Substring(koniec_tytulu + 2, t - koniec_tytulu - 2);

                int u = sLinia.IndexOf(",", t + 1);
                string s14 = sLinia.Substring(u + 1, u - t - 1);
```

The problem appear in the last line .